# Issue with check postgres nagios perl script

Tags: postgresql, perl, nagios

How do I make *check_postgres.pl* file make use of *PGPASSFILE* or *PGPASSWORD* parameters to connect to the database?

I tried setting up the environment variables in my Linux environment, but no success.

Also, is there a way to pass an encrypted password (like a *md5hash*) to the `--dbpass` variable and connect to the database?

Comment: can you show some output of what you've tried?

Comment: 1) MD5 is not an encryption scheme, it's a hashing scheme. There's no way to reverse it, so there's no way to obtain the password in order to send it to the server

Comment: 2) There's no point in encrypting the password. Either you'd have to pass the decryption key to `check_postgres.pl`, or the encrypted password would be just as good as the password. Either way, you don't gain anything.

Answer (score 1):

If https://github.com/bucardo/check_postgres/blob/master/check_postgres.pl is the `check_postgres.pl` you are referring to, it does check the PGPASSWORD environment variable.

The question is then how to make sure that such variable exists on the environment check_postgres.pl is executed.

The nagios docs say to put whatever you need in `/etc/sysconfig/nagios`.

I suspect it depends a lot on how you installed nagios and/or if you installed it with some OS vendor package manager that does things differently, though.

At any rate, the docs: https://support.nagios.com/kb/article.php?id=489